# FreeMarker : diplay tag on condition without if block

Tags: java, xml, freemarker

I am looking for a way to avoid using this in a FreeMarker template :

```
<#if getName()??>
    <Name>getName()</Name>
</#if>
```

Because I need to test many things.

Is there any way to do it by using, for example, a parameter in the tag?
I don't want the tag to be written at all if the value is null. (So exclamation mark is not enough)

Comment: This wasn't the question, but note that generally you can write `name` instead of `getName()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your tags follow the same basic structure:

```
<Tag>value</Tag>
```

you can use a macro, to save yourself some typing:

```
<#macro optional tag value=[]>
    <#if value?has_content>
         <${tag}>${value}</${tag}>
    </#if>
</#macro>
```

and then apply it like this:

```
  <@optional tag='User' value=user/> 
  <@optional tag='Name' value=name/>
```

resulting in the following output code:

```
  <User>myuser</User>
  <Name>myname</User>
```

if one of the properties is not defined the whole tag will be omitted from the output.